# How can I grant users permissions to edit certain views (add/remove fields in a view) in drupal?

Tags: views, users, nodes

We offer a Drupal site to our client with a set of views. The client wants to edit a (predefined) set of views. So, say for example the application got 3 views. The client is allowed to edit one of them.

I have been looking for a module to take care of this but couldn't find any. I was hoping there would be a module which would take the Views tags into account, so you can set permissions on this tag. Say I assign the tag ['Client'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNXqb.png) to a view. I then can assign the edit permission for a certain role on this tag.

How would you solve this or is there already a solution available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your client need only to edit the basic settings of some views (header, footer, title, or empty text...), you should give a try to the [Views UI: Edit Basic Settings](http://drupal.org/project/views_ui_basic) module. It allows you to define which views are editable by a certain role.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that module in my research I guess. I will have a look at it, but actually I was looking for a module where users are also allowed to change the fields shown in the view, not only the basic settings. However, this is a good start :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible. Either a user is allowed to edit fields, or they're not. Having a view editable by the Views UI is also not desirable for version control

One workaround is to use a different content type that they can edit, which is editable as normal, and pull that through into the view.

Chandeep

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. I would partially agree: it is not possible with existing modules; this could be possible in theory with a bit of coding.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same functionality for my latest project, so I created a sandbox module for that.

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/sgurlt/2717137

It adds a permission per view you got. The menu path is not working for now, but i am going to check that soon.